# While deploying react application on github pages i am facing the error-Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

Tags: reactjs, hosting, github-pages

While deploying react application on github pages i am facing the following error.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivmNW.png)

Comment: What are you using to deploy?

Comment: I am using github pages

Comment: Could you please provide the GitHub repo link?